# Save a time to MySQL through JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a database in MySQL and in 1 column I would like to save a number of hours, minutes and seconds greater than 24hrs and not associated to any date.

After doing some research on MySQL I decided the best type for the column with be `TIME`

In Java I have created the entity representing the table with the column type is `java.sql.Time`

When I try to save the time for 192 hours for example I am using `new Time((stf.parse("192:00:00")).getTime())` but this does not work.

Is there a better way to do this or is there another way to save the hours? I am writing a test at the moment to check that my Entity class is correct, which is why I am not using `NamedQueries` or an entity manager.

My Entity Class minus the constructor and getters/setters

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hourslog", uniqueConstraints= {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="idLog")})
public class HrsLog {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
private int idLog;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="idUser", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Timestamp startDate;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Timestamp endDate;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Time hrs;


}
```

Call to Entity constructor and save to db

```
private static void createHrsLog() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    /*
     * Get user from db
     */


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    HrsLog hrs;
    try {
        hrs = new HrsLog(user, new Timestamp((sdf.parse("01-01-2014 00:00:00")).getTime()), new Timestamp((sdf.parse("31-12-2014 23:59:59")).getTime()), new Time((stf.parse("192:00:00")).getTime()));

        session.save(hrs);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in time formatting");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

No errors appear when running the test but the column in the db appears as `00:00:00` not as `192:00:00` which is the expected value

In this case I want to store the number of hours a user can be logged in between the start and end date for example.

Comment: Any reason to use `TIME` for *number of hours greater than 24 and not associated to any date*?

Comment: What's wrong with you know...an integer?

Comment: @nablex I intially thought of using an `INT` but if I want to save 42Hrs and 40min, for example, I need to convert it to decimal and by using a `FLOAT` it wouldn't necessarily be exact as 40mins is 0.666...

Comment: @AleksandrM the MySQL documentation said it could store '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59' which is sufficient for the number of hours i want to store. If there is a better way I am happy to change it but I want it to be precise which is why I don't want to use `INT` or `FLOAT`

Comment: so the requirement is not actually to save the "number of hours", but to save a time. ok. perhaps update the question with that

Comment: @BillyFrost updated sorry if it was not clear initially

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", perhaps you could enlighten people what that means? error message? what SQL is invoked to INSERT the column? What is the Entity code?

Comment: @BillyFrost original post edited to show how the object is being saved to db and the entity

Comment: so what is the SQL to do the INSERT? PS. this is NOT JPA

Comment: Why wouldn't you store 42 hours and 40 minutes as an INT that represents the number of minutes: 42 * 60 + 40 = 2560 ?

Comment: @BillyFrost I don't have any written SQL to do the insert. This is done by JPA as the entity is mapped to the table in the db. Insert is generated by `session.save(hrs);` and then committed by  `session.getTransaction().commit();`

Comment: @alfredaday it didnt occur to me to do that thank you!

Comment: The SQL is in the log, the one that Hibernate uses. It's there so you can debug problems

Comment: @BillyFrost since I am using the javax.persistence package how is it not JPA? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is Hibernate API. You have no such thing as Session, SessionFactory with JPA.

Comment: @BillyFrost as I said I am writing a test at the moment to check that my entity is correct. The entity itself is JPA and will be using the `EntityManager`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get `00:00:00` in the database because [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) is just a thin wrapper around the [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class which represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision. And there are only 24 hours in a day. So you can store values from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` in `java.sql.Time`.

(`new Time((stf.parse("192:00:00")).getTime())` -> `192 % 24 = 0` - Try e.g. with `193:00:00` and you'll see `01:00:00` in database.)

To store hours in a database use `long` type and convert hours to seconds or milliseconds (if you need more precision). It is a very easy conversion and you are probably better off this way when it comes to doing some logic with time, anyway.

Comment: @AleksandrM it was me. I was trying to upvote it using the SO mobile app for android, but i think they've messed up the app and by accident I've downvoted. I've switched my vote, so now this answer is 2+. Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score -1):

I kept the column as a Time column but changed the JPA entity field to a String and it worked perfectly.  From this:

```
@Column(name="some_time_duration")
private Time someTimeDuration;
```

to this

```
@Column(name="some_time_duration")
private String someTimeDuration;
```

I am using JPA 2.0 and mysql 5.6.  It is probably better to just store a number, but this is a scratch table that non techie types are looking at and it's a quick way for them to see the time duration without knowing anything more than select * from foo.

However I agree with the answers above, if you have control of the schema and the data is of real significance to the business data or operations, I would probably just use a long.

Comment: It is not a good solution to store times as strings, since it wastes memory and limits the available operations on the data type.